# Proving two invertible matrices are equal

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

$RTP:(\alpha A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\alpha}A^{-1} $

Where $A$ is an invertible matrix and $\alpha$ is a scalar.

My idea, to prove these matrices are equal, is to multiply both sides with $A$. Then, because $AA^{-1}=I$, we can say that $$\frac{1}{\alpha} I=\frac{1}{\alpha} I$$ Is this valid?

Comment: You should multiply by $\alpha A$ instead, you are assuming you know equality a priori if you multiply by $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
(\alpha A)\left (\frac{1}{\alpha}A^{-1}\right ) \;\; =\;\; \frac{\alpha}{\alpha} AA^{-1} \;\; =\;\; I.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to might how is it that you know that $(\alpha A)^{-a}A=\frac1\alpha\operatorname{Id}$.

However, if you multiply both matrices by $\alpha A$, you get $\operatorname{Id}=\operatorname{Id}$. Since this is true and since $\alpha A$ is invertible, $(\alpha A)^{-1}=\frac1\alpha A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Rather, I believe you should multiply by $\alpha A$ instead.

Doing so for the LHS: $(\alpha A)(\alpha A)^{-1}= I$

And for the RHS: $(\alpha A)\frac{1}{\alpha}A^{-1}= \frac{\alpha}{\alpha} AA^{-1} = I$